# Track the POST request

Tags: php, html, forms

i'm Wondering is there any way to track the incoming post requests in a form?

i have

```
<form method='post'>
<input type='text' name'test' />
<input type='submit' name'submit' />
</form>
```

and i want to allow only specific websites to access the form by curl request,
is it possible to do so ?

// Edit ----------

1) I want to make a script that allow only curl request, but only from certain domains.

2) Use of Referer keys is not in option because they can leak out easily.

Comment: Yes, after you fix the HTML and look for `$_POST['test']`. You can check for the referrer, but that's not very reliable.

Comment: So "track post" means "restrict by user agent"?

Comment: guys i don't want to get the value but restrict the form process for certain websites or allow certain

Comment: You can't see if it is a curl request, they look like usual visitors if they are made right. What you name a website may confuse some readers, as you might mean robots or similar. If you want to stop spammers from sending you messages through your contact form, use a captcha

Comment: and by user agent is not enough because in curl we can change it easily, By The Way thanks for response

Comment: I totally agree with Michael: you should explain what your problem is, rather than how to implement the solution you've figured out. Furthermore, there're lots of HTTP libraries apart from Curl.

Comment: michael, for this form i only want the curl request but only from certain websites. not all, can they be restricted?

Comment: Share your secret with websites and encode requests, as people do for API access.

Comment: not fine, i tried this method but its not tough to get that secret code from others, most of them share them right away, need something to track the request source like domain or somthing Skobaljic

Comment: What they get in return after posting the form? What is the use of this?

Comment: its a PHP script in my server, i don't want to share the script, but the result of it, after inputting data, so they input the required data, but its like everyone want that, but this make my own website slow Skobaljic

Comment: Create a webservice.

Comment: can you give any example, im not sure what are you talking #GuyT

Comment: This is a normal problem for API's, and there are standard ways to deal with it. The simplest is an IP whitelist, as mentioned by JimiDini. Another is a secret key. If you are worried about users sharing their key (im guessing access is charged then?) you can log access and apply a usage limit (eg x number of queries per timeperiod). Who eventually uses these queries is then of little consequence.

Comment: Thanks Steve for your suggestion its valuable to me

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood, you look for an ability to limit requests to curl-callers located on specific servers. If that is the case, then you should just check that `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is in a white-list.

```
<?php
$allowed_ips = ['127.0.0.1', '123.123.123.123'];  // put here the list of IPs
if (!in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $allowed_ips) {
    die();
}
```

Comment: its a good Suggestion but there is a problem, as we know most of website use shared hosting, that mean allowing 1 ip is allowing all those domains in that ip

Comment: well… that's as close as you can get, I'm afraid. because there is NOTHING which would make them different from external point of view. your only other option is to give them personal credentials and take money for number of requests (so they won't want to share the credentials)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion JimiDini, i'll check what can i do more